# Given a strictly upper triangular matrix $A$, is there a closed formula for $(A^k)_{ij}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't want to show that it's nilpotent or anything like that, I just need a formula that describes the $(i,j)$-th entry of $A^k$ with $A$ being strictly upper triangular. I know that is has to be something like:
$$(A^k)_{ij} = \sum_{...}\prod_{...} a_{ij}$$
Does anyone know a book or any other type of reference where such a formula is given?

Comment: Sorry? I don't want to prove the formula, I just need a reference for it for my thesis. The paper I'm working with only uses it implicitly.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a reference, but you should find the following relatively straightforward to prove by induction.

Let $n$ be the size of $A$. For a general matrix $A$, we have
$$
(A^k)_{ij} = \sum_{m_0 = i , m_1,\cdots,m_{k-1},m_{k} = j} \ \prod_{p=1}^k a_{m_{p-1}m_p},
$$
where each $m_p$ is an integer with $1 \leq m_p \leq n$. If $A$ is strictly upper triangular, then the product can only be non-zero if this sequence is strictly increasing, i.e.
$$
i = m_0 < m_1< \cdots < m_{k-1} < m_k = j.
$$

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, that looks good, I'll just prove it myself then, if necessary. :)